# python3 - Delete a node

Tags: data-structures, python-3.6

This code is for deleting a node from a given position in a linked list.

Why do we have to put **return head** in the end?

```
def deleteNode(head, position):
   
   if position == 0:
       return head.next
   
   else:
       curr = head
       for _ in range(position):
           prev=curr
           curr = curr.next
       prev.next=curr.next
       return head
```

Comment: In the case where `position == 0`, the function actually does not do any modification of the list; it simply returns the second node and let the user use that return value to modify their list. Thus the user is probably going to write `mylist = deleteNode(mylist)`. For this to work, you need to return the first node of the list even in the case where you actually removed a node from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to return the list to the function that called this one, in order to keep track of it. `head` is a reference to the beginning of the list, so it is the way to return the list back to where it was.